# Route not defined in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

In My Laravel App I need dispaly collaborators from My collaborators table.
I wrote a query on Collaboration Model as follow

```
public function scopeColabo($query){
 return $query->where('collaborator_id', Auth::user()->id);}
```

and this is My CollaborationController function for this

```
public function newCol(){

 $collaborators = Collaboration::colabo()->get();

 return view('collaborators.new')->withCollaboration($collaborators); }
```

and I have link in My app.blade.php for this display as

```
<li> <a href="{{ route('collaborators.new') }}">Collaborate</a> </li>
```

and this is My routes.php

```
Route::post('projects/{projects}/collaborator', [
'uses' => 'ProjectCollaboratorsController@newCol',
'as'   => 'projects.collaborators.collaborator',]);
```

but I get following error message

```
Route [collaborators.new] not defined. (View: C:\Users\fernando\Desktop\c\resources\views\layouts\app.blade.php)
```

what can I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is you are indeed trying to call a route that does not exist. In your routes file you are labelling the route `'as'   => 'projects.collaborators.collaborator'` so with that being said, this should be updated as such:

```
<li> <a href="{{ route('projects.collaborators.collaborator') }}">Collaborate</a> </li>
```

EDIT: Apologies, pasted the wrong line of code from your sample. The line above needs to be updated.

Comment: paste your code but generate following error.."Missing required parameters for [Route: projects.collaborators.collaborator] [URI: projects/{projects}/collaborator]."

Answer (score 0):

I did it with My routes.php paste this code

```
Route::resource('collaborators', 'ProjectCollaboratorsController');
```

it is working